# Execute macro on incoming mail if specific mail subject is given

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have programmed a macro that should extract the content of received mails into an Excel sheet if the mail subject contains a specific word.

All in all its working, but the macro executes as soon as I receive a mail. That leads to a pop-up window in Outlook every time I receive a mail, but I only want it to pop up if I receive a mail with the specific subject.

I have to find another solution for the line:

`If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then Set olMail = item`

The entire code:

```vb
Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    
    'Variablen dimensionieren
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oxLApp As Object, oxLwb As Object, oxLws As Object
    
    Set oxLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set oxLwb = oxLApp.Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Users\A2000\Desktop\Makros_NewScoping")
    Set oxLws = oxLwb.Sheets("Slide 3")
    
    'Prüfen ob Item eine Mail ist
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    
        Set olMail = item
        
        If InStr(olMail.Subject, "APPROVAL REQUIRED") And _
          olMail.SenderName = "Test, Name" Then
    
            With oxLws
                .Range("Q24") = olMail.VotingResponse
                .Range("E41") = olMail.Body
            End With
        End If
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Note that [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). With `If InStr(olMail.Subject, "APPROVAL REQUIRED")` you already check the subject of the mail. So I don't get what exactly your issue is.

Comment: You've not shown all the code, so you might need more than this.. but you open the spreadsheet before you test if it's a MailItem or not. Try moving your 3 `Set` lines of code *inside* your `If TypeName(item)...` block?

Comment: The problem is, that every time a macro accesses to outlook, a pop-up window shows up where I have to accept the access. Which would be okay, if the trigger for the outlook access would be a mail with a specific subject. But now (with the code above), every incoming mail triggers outlook access which leads to a pop-up window every time I get a mail. Could I make it clearer?

Comment: My idea was something like this: If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" And InStr(olMail.Subject, "APPROVAL REQUIRED") And _
olMail.SenderName = "Test, Name" Then
Set olMail = item
This would only execute the macro if the specific mail subject is given. Unfortunately this doesn’t work because ‚olmail‘ can’t be used before the line ‚Set olmail = item‘.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to run any extra code if the mail arrived doesn't correspond to your conditions:

```
Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

  'Variablen dimensionieren
  Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim oxLApp As Object, oxLwb As Object, oxLws As Object

  'Prüfen ob Item eine Mail ist
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set olMail = item
    
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "APPROVAL REQUIRED") And _
olMail.SenderName = "Test, Name" Then

       Set oxLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
       Set oxLwb = oxLApp.Workbooks.Open _
("C:\Users\A2000\Desktop\Makros_NewScoping")
       Set oxLws = oxLwb.Sheets("Slide 3")

       With oxLws

         .Range("Q24") = olMail.VotingResponse
         .Range("E41") = olMail.Body
    
       End With
     End If
```

Note, creating a new Excel instance each time a new item is added to the folder is not really a good idea. Moreover, the ItemAdd event is fired not only for incoming emails, but also for every email moved to the folder. So, when an item is moved to the folder you will get the code triggered.

That is why I'd suggest handling the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, it is not a good idea to trigger excel every time I receive a new mail. An alternative solution could be, to check every few days if emails with a specific subject were received in the past days. If yes, the needed content (VotingResponse & Body) could be extracted into the excel. But however, thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code that opens Excel to below the `If` statement where you check the server and the subject.